# objective-c passing parameters to a view

Tags: objective-c, view, uiview, parameter-passing

I'm doing an app for study that from an introview go to another view throught 4 custom buttons.
to each button is bind an url that is èpassed as parameter to the segue that go to the other view, were there is a webview that displays the given url. 
everything is working, but there is a strange bug:
the first time I touch each of the button in the first view a null value is passed to the other view 
all the other times, everyting works fine...

this is the code:

```
///this is the action linked to the buttons
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender];

    if (sender==btnImg1){
        linkz = linkUrl1;
    }else if (sender==btnImg2){
        linkz = linkUrl2;
    }else if (sender==btnImg3){
        linkz = linkUrl3;
    }else if (sender==btnImg4){
        linkz = linkUrl4;
    }
      NSLog(@"msg: %@", linkz);
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
        // Get the destination view
        SecondView *og = [segue destinationViewController];
        // Set the selected vaue in the new view
        [og setNavigationUrl:linkz];
    }
}
```

any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Check have u created property and synthesized NavigationUrl in SecondView

Comment: Shouldn't you set `linkz` *before* calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:]` ?

Comment: @astlab: You are welcome. I have added it as an answer so that you can "accept" it by clicking on the check mark outline to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `linkz` before calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:]`.